# Possible to add javascript to Zend_Form_Element_Radio?

Tags: php, zend-form

Ultimately, I'd like my Zend Form to render this HTML:

```
<p>Do you have any documents to upload?</p>
<p>Yes <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="uploadChoice" onClick="showTable()">&nbsp;&nbsp;No <input type="radio" value="No" name="uploadChoice" onClick="hideTable()" checked></p>
```

Here's what I have in my Zend_Form:

```
//create radio buttons
$uploadQuestion = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('upLoadQuestion');
$uploadQuestion->setLabel('Do you have any documents to upload?')
->addMultiOptions(array(
'yes' => 'Yes',
'no' => 'No'
))
->setSeparator(' ');
```

The problem I'm running into is how to add the onClick="showTable()" and onClick="hideTable()" elements to their respective radio buttons.

In the alternative, I could rework the javascript and add something like onClick="toggleTable()" to the radio buttons if I can't add something different to each of the radio buttons. But, will Zend let me do that?

Comment: Your html code is showing 2 different Radio Elements, your zend form is using one element ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use setAttrib like this:

```
$uploadQuestion->setAttrib('onClick','showTable();');
```

Obviously, in this case, you'll have to use the same JS function for all the radio buttons of the "uploadQuestion" radiogroup.

Hope it will help somenone.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do this with javascript? You don't need your onclick to be inside input element. Just use javascript to pull it by id and then add event listener.

Alternatively, you might be interested in this post http://paveldubinin.com/2011/04/zend-form-radio-buttons/ describing how to solve this by splitting radio group into set of independent radiobutton elements, but which behave as a single.

You can then assign any parameters (including onlclick if you like) to these individual radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your code:

```
->setAttrib('onclick', 'showHideFields()')
```

then just add jquery script, something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
function showHideFields(){
          if($("input[type='radio']:checked").val()==='1'){
             //is checked
          }else if($("input[type='radio']:checked").val()==='0'){
             //is not checked
          }
}
</script>
```

ps. i try with my code

```
->setAttrib('onclick', 'showHideFields();')
```

AND IT DIDNT WORK so i try

```
->setAttrib('onclick', 'showHideFields()')
```

AND IT WORK CORRECTLY (zf 1.12)